# Stylesheet referencing a variable in curly braces doesn't compile

Tags: java, xslt

I am trying to perform an XSLT transformation in Java. Here is the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="person">
        <xsl:variable name="varname">info</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$varname}">content</xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(It's a very simplified example demonstrating the problem. In fact, I really need to define the variable and then use it).

Here is the Java code:

```
DocumentBuilder builder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=builder.parse(new File("C:\\temp\\test.xsl"));
DOMSource xsl=new DOMSource(doc);
Transformer transformer=TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
```

When running, it emits an exception:

```
ERROR:  'Variable or parameter 'varname' is undefined.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:824)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:619)
```

The same stylesheet works fine in other engines (in Internet Explorer, in MSXML, in GNU xsltproc). What am I doing wrong? Maybe this feature is not supported in Java? Or maybe I should first set some parameters to the TransformerFactory or whatever?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using JDK 1.6.0_26, neither with the built-in xalan version nor with xalan 2.7.1, which version are your using? Maybe you could also include the relevant source of your `MyXMLReader` class.

Comment: @Jörn, I am using JDK 1.6.0_24 (64-bit). Same result on JDK 1.5, differing only in line numbers in the stack trace.

Comment: I have edited the question, replacing `MyXMLReader` with standard classes `DocumentBuilderFactory` etc. The error is still the same.

Comment: Also, the same error when running on JRE 1.6.0_26-b03. I guess the behaviour should depend more on the JRE where the code is run than on the JDK which compiled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the error message is entirely misleading. The actual problem is that the `DocumentBuilder` is not configured to be namespace aware, and so does not recognize the `xsl:variable` declaration. The parser somehow still recognizes the expression in curly braces. You can fix the problem by enabling namespace aware parsing on the `DocumentBuilderFactory`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new File("C:\\temp\\test.xsl"));
```